Using post filter to remove entries whereby collapsed inner hits total is less than X
So I have an elastic query that collapses based on a field that represents a hash value that at most is shared by no more than two entries. I need to understand how to potentially filter out those entries whereby following collapse the total is 1 and not 2, i.e. keep the items whereby there are two collapsed items within inner hits. I have tried to use post filter but the inner_hits object is not available and hence the total can not be queried.
Elastic version : 7.10
Would you have any suggestions, sample of query is below...
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "someHash"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          // ... other must items ... //
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        // ... filter items ... //
      ],
      "must_not": [
        // ... must not items ... //
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "someHash",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "same_hash",
      "size": 2
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "someHash"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "entityId": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "inner_hits.same_hash.hits.total": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100
}

